# variable cannot be accessed by the test

Tags: java, eclipse, evaluator

```
public class Saiyan extends PlayableFighter {
private boolean transformed;
public Saiyan(....)
{
    :
    :
}

public void isTransformed(boolean x){
transformed=x;

}
public boolean isTransformed(){
    return transformed;
}
```

}

i think my transformed attribute should be read and write but when i run my test i get this  error

```
M1PrivateTest.testSaiyanClassWRITEVariables 0/1  
   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
   The "transformed" instance variable in
    class Saiyan is a WRITE variable. 
    at M1PrivateTest.testSaiyanClassWRITEVariables(Unknown Source) at  
      java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at
       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What does the test code look like?

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
public void setTransformed(boolean transformed){
    this.transformed=transformed;
}
```

as per normal setters/getters pattern